# JetBrains IDE - how to disable fancy conditional operators that affect the display of != == >= and <=

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, goland

I have seen some engineers add something to make JetBrains IDEs (such as IntelliJ, PhpStorm, GoLand, etc) replace conditional operators such as `!=`, `==`, `>=` and `<=` with some fancy representation like ≠, ≥, ≤, etc

However in recent versions it seems that this may now be the default behavior.

I personally do not care for it and want to know how to disable it but didn't know what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of time searching I learned that this feature is called "Font Ligatures"

So if you search for `Ligatures` in the settings of any JetBrains IDE (I did it in GoLand) you will find it only in a few places, I found it and disabled it in `Editor` > `Reader Mode` first and then the other locations already had it unchecked not sure if they unchecked when I unchecked the first one or if they where already in that state

This change did NOT take effect in my already-open editor windows until closing GoLand and re-opening it.  Once re-opened then my ==, >=, <=, != where all back the way I like them :)

I am putting this here on StackOverflow attempting to use the keywords I originally searched for trying to solve this in hopes that it helps someone else.

Comment: Reader Mode is enabled for non-project/excluded/library/read-only files and has some separate settings to what you actually will have for normal Editor (e.g. disabled inspections, font ligatures etc).